# Send email using laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a contact form and I want to send email to the admin of the page when a visitor sends a message from the contact form.

```
  public function send(Request $request){
        Mail::send('email.message',[
            'request' => $request
        ], function($m) use ($request) {
            $m->from($request->email);
            $m->to('mail@domain.com', 'Name')->subject('Your Reminder!');
        });
   }
```

How can I configure it to send email without using gmail?

Comment: Have you changed your .env file mail settings? You should put the driver, host, auth, port, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should read the docs about sending Mail using Laravel and its drivers e.g. Mailgun

http://laravel.com/docs/master/mail