# Mail::send() returns zero and no errors, still no mail sent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to send my first email using L5.1 and Gmail account. I have 2-steps verification and I'm using specific app password in my .env file. When I try to send the email with:

```
    $result =Mail::send('emails.contact', $request->all(), function($msg)
    {
        $msg->subject   =   'Mail from Contact Page';
        $msg->to        =   'contact@fakedomain.com';
    }); dd($result);
```

Then $result is always zero and no mail is sent (I checked the spam folder 1000 times). I also tried using mailtrap.io with credentials supplied and still the result is the same in browser and also using Tinker. 
Here's my .env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=pandora
DB_USERNAME=myDatabaseUser
DB_PASSWORD=myDatabasePassword

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myUser@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=AppSpecificPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I also authorized the app in Gmail settings. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post your `.env` file. Are you sure you've configured your Gmail settings correctly (SMTP host, port, etc)?

Comment: Mail config values look fine. What does `dump(Mail::failures());` output if you run it after `Mail::send()`?

Comment: have you run php artisan config:cache after updating your config. env file?

Comment: Mail::failures() is an empty array.  I restarted Apache and ran php artisan config:cache and still no errors and no email sent

Comment: From what I could track in the source code of SwiftMailer (which Laravel uses to send mails), the failures array gets populated when there is an exception thrown at any point in the process, which gets passed by reference up until the Laravel's [mailer class](http://bit.ly/1XLCEco), so it would stand to reason that there's no problem with the mailer. Have you tried using an email client to connect to that email address with the application password? Also have you checked the "Sent" folder of the Gmail address that you're sending from to see if the emails are present there by any chance?

Comment: Do you have SwiftMailer installed?

Comment: I didn't actively installed SwiftMailer, should I do it? I switched to a new account not using 2-steps verification, I received the alert from Gmail that a less secure app was trying to access the account, then I turned on access to less secure apps, but I still got nothing on sent mails or inbox.  Also I installed Thunderbird and I configured this account and it works

Comment: I tried and failed with:      `$result =Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', function ($message) {
            $message->subject   =   'Mail from contact';
            $message->to        =   'myAddress@gmail.com';
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737545/send-email-using-laravel/32737735#32737735)

SO, I change mi code to:

```
    $result = Mail::send('emails.contact',$request->all(), function($message) use ($request) {
        $message->from($request->email);
        $message->to('myAddress@gmail.com')
            ->subject($request->subject)
            ->replyTo($request->email);
    });
```

For some reason **From** is always what's configured in my L5.1 settings but I can live with that.
Thanks [@bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351330/bogdan) for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

This is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=asd@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=emailpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

[Follow this](http://learninglaravel.net/learn-to-send-emails-using-gmail-and-sendgrid-in-laravel-5)

Comment: I changed MAIL_ENCRYPTION to tls (that's the only difference I can see) and got this message:  Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""